# How to use properties with the SimpleRegistry in Apache Camel (Spring XML)

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I want to use a SimpleRegistry to store properties (as global variables). The property is changed with `setProperty` in a route with a jms endpoint.  The camel documentation changed last week and has many dead links, also the Registry page. I did not found any samples that describe the use of the simpleRegistry.

I used the [camel-example-servlet-tomcat](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-servlet-tomcat) as base. I do not use Fuse or the patched camel wildfly, because is to huge for our simple module.

```xml
<beans .... >
   .
   .
   .
  <bean id="simpleRegistry" class="org.apache.camel.support.SimpleRegistry" />

  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="ref:simpleRegistry" />
    <route id="storeConfig">
      <from id="myTopic" uri="jms:topic:myTopic?selector=Configuration %3D 'xyz'" />
      <log id="printHeader2" message="Received header: ${headers}" />
      <log id="logToken" message="Received token: ${headers[myToken]}" />
      <setProperty id="setMyToken" name="myProperty">
        <simple>${headers[myToken]}</simple>
      </setProperty>
    </route>
    <route id="externalIncomingDataRoute">
      <from uri="servlet:hello" />
      <transform>
            <simple>The Token is: {{myProperty}}</simple>
      </transform>
    </route>
  </camelContext>
</beans>
```

With the camel context deined like above, I got a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` **Properties simpleRegistry not found in registry.**

When I use `<propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="classpath:test.properties" />` and create a test.properties file, everything works fine but I cannot change the property. The operation in the `setProperty` tag is ignored.

The reason why I need a global variable is, I send a dynamic configuration (the myToken) via a jms topic to the camel context. A single route should store this configuration globaly. If an other route is called via an rest component, this route need the token to make a choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can achieve the same result following the below approach which uses the PropertiesComponent

```
<bean id="applicationProperties" class="java.util.Properties"/>

<bean id="properties" class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:application.properties"/>
    <property name="overrideProperties" ref="applicationProperties" />
</bean>
```

Define the property place holder in the camel context:

```
<propertyPlaceholder id="propertiesRef" location="ref:applicationProperties" />
```

Set a property as shown below :

```
<bean ref="applicationProperties" method="setProperty(token, 'Test'})" />
```

And to fetch the property :  ${properties:token}

Answer (score 1):

OK, there are multiple subjects in your question.

1. You write you want to use Camel SimpleRegistry, but you obviously have a Spring application.

If you got Spring available, the **Camel Registry automatically uses the Spring bean registry**. The [Camel Registry is just a thin wrapper](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/registry.html) or provider interface that uses **whenever possible an available registry of another framework**.

**The Camel SimpleRegistry is only used when nothing else is available**. This is basically an in-memory registry based on a Map.

2. You want to set an application property with `<setProperty>`.

`<setProperty>` sets an **Exchange property**, NOT an application property. With this you can save values in the [Exchange of a message](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/exchange.html).

3. You want to use "global variables".

You could perhaps use a Spring singleton bean that is a Map. You could then autowire it where you need it, it would be like an application wide available map.

However, **think twice why you need this kind of variable**. This could also be a symptom of a design problem.